# VIEWS with SELECT inside conditions delaying the query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view

In one of my SQL views I am using an inline select statement with a where clause.

The outline of my view is like

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_autumn]
AS
    SELECT 
        BookNumber, Title, shopNo
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             BookNumber, Title, shopNO
         FROM  
             (SELECT DISTINCT 
                  (sum_vnr) AS BookNumber,
                  navn1 AS Title,
                  tik AS ShopNO,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sum_vnr, tik ORDER BY sum_vnr DESC) AS rownumber
              FROM  
                  sum s
              INNER JOIN 
                  hod h ON s.tik = h.tik
              WHERE 
                  s.aar = (SELECT currentyear
                           FROM SemesterInfo
                           WHERE SemName = 'Autumn')
                  AND CAST(s.sum_vnr AS BIGINT) > 10000
                  AND (s.id LIKE 'h%' OR s.id LIKE 'H%' OR s.id LIKE 'j%'
                       OR s.id LIKE 'J%')) a
    WHERE rownumber = 1
    ) b
LEFT JOIN (
    ------
    ) p ON b.ShopNO = p.tikk
    AND b.ISBN = p.vnr
LEFT JOIN table_k k ON p.aar = k.aar

GO
```

And if I remove the WHERE clause of

```
 WHERE 
     s.aar = (SELECT currentyear
              FROM SemesterInfo
              WHERE SemName = 'Autumn')
```

and shorten it to

```
WHERE s.aar =19
```

I am getting the result of view very quickly. But I am trying to add some dynamic nature to this query and selecting this constant from a settings table

Any thoughts on this? Why is the query taking an indefinite time to load with an inline `Where` clause?

Comment: What does SemesterInfo contain?

Comment: its a key-value pair only in form of currentYear SemInfo , So  this select will always return a number 19 or 20 or 21 or whatever is set for the key ,. Here Key value used is Autumn

Comment: How many rows? Does it have indexes? What's the difference in the execution plans?

Comment: @ZoharPeled the inline select is just a selection from a table of 3-5 records only

Comment: Should probalby check the actual execution plan. And perhaps post it in xml format on [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) if you want performance tuning. In queries with an inner query reliant on an outer value, it's expected. But in this case there's something going on underneath, where you'll need the plan for to see what, or else it's just guess work.

Answer (score 0):

:try with IN insted of =

```
 WHERE 
     s.aar in (SELECT currentyear
              FROM SemesterInfo
              WHERE SemName = 'Autumn')
```

Comment: IN is not making any difference

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the subquery as a join.

```
INNER JOIN SemesterInfo si
ON s.aer = si.currentYear
WHERE si.SemName = 'Autumn'
```

If that doesn't do it, consider keeping this syntax and creating an index on SemName